# Problem adding image to ckeditor in certain position

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm facing a problem adding images dynamically to a CKEditor 4.11.2 container when using easy-image plugin.

I have a list of images and need to add the selected image to the editor when double clicking on them. I'm currently getting the editor content, find my target image table and adding them to the first free empty cell. 
That's working fine for simple images, but it's getting tricky when using easy-image plugin because its features as add caption are not getting loaded.
[image]

I already tried,

**1:** Adding dynamically the `<figure><img><figcaption>` html instead of simple `<img>`. That gives the "captioned" style, but not working dynamically as well.

```
var doc = (editor && editor.document && editor.document.getBody().$);
var cnt = $('[' + MYTABLE + ']', doc).get(0);
var img = <figure><img src="" /><figcaption>caption</figcaption></figure>;
cnt.find('TD').each(function () {
    var td = $(this);
    if ($('img', td).length < 1) {
        td.html(img);
        added = true;
    }
});
```

**2:** Reloading editor content data, `CKEDITOR.instaces.editor.setData(CKEDITOR.instaces.editor.getData());`, that works fine, but cause the "flash" reload of editor and the editor scroll flies to the top.

Is there any function as "insertContent" in ckeditor5, that adds the content taking in consideration its content?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide us with a snippet? that way we can help you faster.

Comment: Thanks in advance. Added sniped and image.